# intervals for contrasts at specific values of covariate - emmeans and bootMer

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I've been learning `emmeans` (great package) and using it to generate confidence intervals for contrasts of levels of a categorical variable (variable **m**) at specific values of a continuous variable (variable **s**), and I'd like to know if the same thing is possible using `bootMer` from lme4.

I've pasted in the results of running `sjPlot::plot_model` on the model to help visualization.  I know that the confidence intervals for the *contrasts* are not shown on the plot, but I'm interested in knowing how to obtain the point estimates and confidence intervals for:

- the B-A contrast at s=1
- the B-A contrast at s=5
- the C-A contrast at s=1
- the C-A contrast at s=5

I'm not trying to control the family-wise error rate, so adjusting for multiple comparisons isn't necessarily needed.

[image: plot_model output]

I would have used `predict()`, but that doesn't work to get confidence intervals (no `interval="confidence"`) for lmer models, with the recommendation to use `bootMer` instead found in the help for predict.merMod.  Unfortunately I still haven't been able to figure out how to get the same four confidence intervals using `bootMer` as I have with `emmeans`.  Is it even possible?  If not, is that because it's not statistically legitimate and I'm just confused about things?

```
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)
library(ggplot2)
library(sjPlot)

# create the dataset, unbalanced at the lowest stratum ( 2 repeats for L2 instead of 3)
set.seed(1234)
s_levels <- 1:5
m_levels <- c("A", "B", "C")
v_levels <- c("L2", "L3", "L4")
reps <- 1:3
df <- expand.grid(rep=reps, s=s_levels, m=m_levels, v=v_levels)
df$y <- 10 + as.numeric(as.factor(df$v))*0.1 + rnorm(nrow(df), mean=0, sd=0.1)
df$subunit <- as.factor(paste(df$v,"-",df$m,"-",df$s, sep=""))
df <- subset(df, !(rep==3 & v=="L2"))  # drop the 3rd repeat for v=="L2"

# fit the with-interaction model using lmer()
fit <- lmer(y ~ 1 + v + m*s + (1|subunit), data=df)

# emmeans confidence intervals with size fixed = 1
ref_grid(fit, at=list(s = 1))
fit_rg <- ref_grid(fit, at=list(s = 1))
fit_emmeans <- emmeans(fit_rg, specs=~m*s)
contrast(fit_emmeans, method="trt.vs.ctrl1", infer=TRUE, adjust="none")

# emmeans confidence intervals with size fixed = 5
ref_grid(fit, at=list(s = 5))
fit_rg <- ref_grid(fit, at=list(s = 5))
fit_emmeans <- emmeans(fit_rg, specs=~m*s)
contrast(fit_emmeans, method="trt.vs.ctrl1", infer=TRUE, adjust="none")

# requires sjPlot library
plot_model(
  model = fit ,
  type="pred" ,
  terms=c("s", "m", "v") ,
  ci.lvl = 0.95)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with bootMer so can't help with this - but could you please provide a source for the recommendation to use bootMer over predict()? I have regularly used predict.lmer() with lmer objects.

Comment: You've gotten it to work with `interval="confidence"` ?   The help for predict.merMod says "There is no option for computing standard errors of predictions because it is difficult to define an efficient method that incorporates uncertainty in the variance parameters; we recommend bootMer for this task."

Comment: Lachlan, I've updated my question to be more clear about the `interval="confidence"` part.  If you somehow _have_ been able to use predict() to generate confidence intervals for lmer models, please let me know!